# Efficient EnumSet + List

Tags: java

Someone knows a nice solution for [EnumSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) + List

I mean I need to store enum values and I also need to preserve the order , and to be able to access its index of the enum value in the collection in O(1) time.

Comment: What order are you trying to preserve?  The order you inserted the values into the set?

Comment: Importantly do you also want the other notable property of Set, i.e. that it does not permit duplicates? That will make a big difference to the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can come to think of, present in the API is the `LinkedHashSet`:

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.

---

I doubt it's possible to do what you want. Basically, you want to look up indexes in constant time, even after modifying the order of the list. Unless you allow remove / reorder operations to take O(n) time, I believe you can't get away with lower than O(log n) (which can be achieved by a heap structure).

Comment: That could be actually a nice alternative. I just need to check out the overhead of this linked / Hash implementation. I actually need something really small and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to satisfy ordering *and* O(1) access is to duplicate the data in a `List` and an array of indexes (wrapped in a nice little `OrderedEnumSet`, of course).

Comment: If I remove something from the middle of the list, I would have to update the array of indexes in O(n), no?